# Installing Shogun toolbox with MacPorts for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, macports, shogun

I am having a hard time trying to install the Shogun machine-learning toolbox via MacPorts. It seems that the only version MacPorts has [declares Python 2.6 as a dependency](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/math/shogun/Portfile) and as a result MacPorts downloads and installs Python 2.6, numPy for Python 2.6 etc. The problem is I have Python 2.7 already installed and a host of other packages, including numPy, that I want to use with shogun already installed under Python 2.7.

Has anyone had success using shogun with Python 2.7. I couldn't find any documentation stating it only works with 2.6, so I assume 2.7 should work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it needs to be converted to a python Portgroup port where the python version is implied from the current python see py-scipy for an example depending on py-numpy.

Also see the current threads on the [macports mailing list](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2011-December/thread.html) for octave.